# How to crop video from top?

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation

I am trying to create square video and for that I am using 640*480 camera view but not able to crop video from top? I have tried many thing but no success. so please suggest how to do it, What transform is helpful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage:

Create a property (or any other variable to hold the VideoTranscoder)

```
self.videoTranscoder = [SCVideoTranscoder new];
self.videoTranscoder.asset = PUT_UR_AVASSET_HERE;
self.videoTranscoder.outputURL = PUT_A_FILE_URL_HERE;

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
self.videoTranscoder.completionBlock = ^(BOOL success){
    //PUT YOUR CODE HERE WHEN THE TRANSCODING IS DONE...
};
[self.videoTranscoder start];
```

You can cancel the transcoding process, if you just call `[transcoder cancel]`.

**SCVideoTranscoder.h file**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SCVideoTranscoder : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAsset *asset;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL cancelled;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSURL *outputURL;

@property (nonatomic, strong) void (^completionBlock)(BOOL success);

- (void)start;
- (void)cancel;

@end
```

**SCVideoTranscoder.m file**
In the file you can find that I setup the video to be 480x480, you can ofc. change this to the value you like!

```
#import "SCVideoTranscoder.h"

@interface SCVideoTranscoder()

@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t mainSerializationQueue;

@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t rwAudioSerializationQueue;

@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t rwVideoSerializationQueue;

@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t dispatchGroup;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAssetReader* assetReader;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAssetWriter* assetWriter;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *assetReaderAudioOutput;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAssetReaderTrackOutput *assetReaderVideoOutput;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterAudioInput;
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterVideoInput;

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL audioFinished;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL videoFinished;

@end

@implementation SCVideoTranscoder

- (void)start
{
    NSString *serializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ serialization queue", self];

    // Create the main serialization queue.
    self.mainSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([serializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);
    NSString *rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ rw audio serialization queue", self];

    // Create the serialization queue to use for reading and writing the audio data.
    self.rwAudioSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([rwAudioSerializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);
    NSString *rwVideoSerializationQueueDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ rw video serialization queue", self];

    // Create the serialization queue to use for reading and writing the video data.
    self.rwVideoSerializationQueue = dispatch_queue_create([rwVideoSerializationQueueDescription UTF8String], NULL);

    self.cancelled = NO;
    // Asynchronously load the tracks of the asset you want to read.
    [self.asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks"] completionHandler:^{
        // Once the tracks have finished loading, dispatch the work to the main serialization queue.
        dispatch_async(self.mainSerializationQueue, ^{
            // Due to asynchronous nature, check to see if user has already cancelled.
            if (self.cancelled)
                return;
            BOOL success = YES;
            NSError *localError = nil;
            // Check for success of loading the assets tracks.
            success = ([self.asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&localError] == AVKeyValueStatusLoaded);
            if (success)
            {
                // If the tracks loaded successfully, make sure that no file exists at the output path for the asset writer.
                NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
                NSString *localOutputPath = [self.outputURL path];
                if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:localOutputPath])
                    success = [fm removeItemAtPath:localOutputPath error:&localError];
            }
            if (success)
            {
                success = [self setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter:&localError];
                if (success)
                {
                    [self startAssetReaderAndWriter:&localError];
                }else{
                    [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:success withError:localError];
                }
            }
        });
    }];
}

- (BOOL)setupAssetReaderAndAssetWriter:(NSError **)outError
{
    // Create and initialize the asset reader.
    self.assetReader = [[AVAssetReader alloc] initWithAsset:self.asset error:outError];
    BOOL success = (self.assetReader != nil);
    if (success)
    {
        // If the asset reader was successfully initialized, do the same for the asset writer.
        self.assetWriter = [[AVAssetWriter alloc] initWithURL:self.outputURL fileType:AVFileTypeMPEG4 error:outError];
        success = (self.assetWriter != nil);
    }

    if (success)
    {
        // If the reader and writer were successfully initialized, grab the audio and video asset tracks that will be used.
        AVAssetTrack *assetAudioTrack = nil, *assetVideoTrack = nil;
        NSArray *audioTracks = [self.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
        if ([audioTracks count] > 0)
            assetAudioTrack = [audioTracks objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *videoTracks = [self.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([videoTracks count] > 0)
            assetVideoTrack = [videoTracks objectAtIndex:0];

        if (assetAudioTrack)
        {
            // If there is an audio track to read, set the decompression settings to Linear PCM and create the asset reader output.
            NSDictionary *decompressionAudioSettings = @{ AVFormatIDKey : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatLinearPCM] };
            self.assetReaderAudioOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:assetAudioTrack outputSettings:decompressionAudioSettings];
            if (DEBUG) {
                self.assetReader.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMake(20, 1));
            }else{
                self.assetReader.timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, CMTimeMake(10, 1));
            }

            [self.assetReader addOutput:self.assetReaderAudioOutput];
            // Then, set the compression settings to 128kbps AAC and create the asset writer input.
            AudioChannelLayout stereoChannelLayout = {
                .mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo,
                .mChannelBitmap = 0,
                .mNumberChannelDescriptions = 0
            };
            NSData *channelLayoutAsData = [NSData dataWithBytes:&stereoChannelLayout length:offsetof(AudioChannelLayout, mChannelDescriptions)];
            NSDictionary *compressionAudioSettings = @{
                                                       AVFormatIDKey         : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
                                                       AVEncoderBitRateKey   : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:128000],
                                                       AVSampleRateKey       : [NSNumber numberWithInteger:44100],
                                                       AVChannelLayoutKey    : channelLayoutAsData,
                                                       AVNumberOfChannelsKey : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:2]
                                                       };
            self.assetWriterAudioInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:[assetAudioTrack mediaType] outputSettings:compressionAudioSettings];
            [self.assetWriter addInput:self.assetWriterAudioInput];
        }

        if (assetVideoTrack)
        {
            // If there is a video track to read, set the decompression settings for YUV and create the asset reader output.
            NSDictionary *decompressionVideoSettings = @{
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey     : [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_422YpCbCr8],
                                                         (id)kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey : [NSDictionary dictionary]
                                                         };
            self.assetReaderVideoOutput = [AVAssetReaderTrackOutput assetReaderTrackOutputWithTrack:assetVideoTrack outputSettings:decompressionVideoSettings];
            [self.assetReader addOutput:self.assetReaderVideoOutput];
            CMFormatDescriptionRef formatDescription = NULL;
            // Grab the video format descriptions from the video track and grab the first one if it exists.
            NSArray *videoFormatDescriptions = [assetVideoTrack formatDescriptions];
            if ([videoFormatDescriptions count] > 0)
                formatDescription = (__bridge CMFormatDescriptionRef)[videoFormatDescriptions objectAtIndex:0];
            CGSize trackDimensions = {
                .width = 0.0,
                .height = 0.0,
            };
            CGAffineTransform videoTransform = [assetVideoTrack preferredTransform];
            // If the video track had a format description, grab the track dimensions from there. Otherwise, grab them direcly from the track itself.
            if (formatDescription)
                trackDimensions = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetPresentationDimensions(formatDescription, false, false);
            else
                trackDimensions = [assetVideoTrack naturalSize];

            int width = 480;
            int height = 480;
            int bitrate = 1000000;
            NSDictionary *compressionSettings = @{
                                                  AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:bitrate],AVVideoMaxKeyFrameIntervalKey: @(150),
                                                  AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel,
                                                  AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey: @NO,
                                                  AVVideoH264EntropyModeKey: AVVideoH264EntropyModeCAVLC,
                                                  AVVideoExpectedSourceFrameRateKey: @(30)
                                                  };
            if ([SCDeviceModel speedgrade]==0) {
                width = 320;
                height = 320;
                compressionSettings = @{
                                        AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:bitrate],
                                        AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264BaselineAutoLevel,
                                        AVVideoAllowFrameReorderingKey: @NO};
            }

            NSDictionary *videoSettings  =
            @{
              AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
              AVVideoScalingModeKey: AVVideoScalingModeResizeAspectFill,
              AVVideoWidthKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:width],
              AVVideoHeightKey: [NSNumber numberWithInt:height],
              AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: compressionSettings};

            // Create the asset writer input and add it to the asset writer.
            self.assetWriterVideoInput = [AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:[assetVideoTrack mediaType] outputSettings:videoSettings];
            self.assetWriterVideoInput.transform = videoTransform;
            [self.assetWriter addInput:self.assetWriterVideoInput];
        }
    }
    return success;
}

- (void)startAssetReaderAndWriter:(NSError **)outError
{
    BOOL success = YES;
    // Attempt to start the asset reader.
    success = [self.assetReader startReading];
    if (!success)
        *outError = [self.assetReader error];
    if (success)
    {
        // If the reader started successfully, attempt to start the asset writer.
        success = [self.assetWriter startWriting];
        if (!success)
            *outError = [self.assetWriter error];
    }

    if (success)
    {
        // If the asset reader and writer both started successfully, create the dispatch group where the reencoding will take place and start a sample-writing session.
        self.dispatchGroup = dispatch_group_create();
        [self.assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime:kCMTimeZero];
        self.audioFinished = NO;
        self.videoFinished = NO;

        if (self.assetWriterAudioInput)
        {
            // If there is audio to reencode, enter the dispatch group before beginning the work.
            dispatch_group_enter(self.dispatchGroup);
            // Specify the block to execute when the asset writer is ready for audio media data, and specify the queue to call it on.
            [self.assetWriterAudioInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:self.rwAudioSerializationQueue usingBlock:^{
                // Because the block is called asynchronously, check to see whether its task is complete.
                if (self.audioFinished)
                    return;
                BOOL completedOrFailed = NO;
                // If the task isn't complete yet, make sure that the input is actually ready for more media data.
                while ([self.assetWriterAudioInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] && !completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Get the next audio sample buffer, and append it to the output file.
                    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self.assetReaderAudioOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
                    if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        BOOL success = [self.assetWriterAudioInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                        sampleBuffer = NULL;
                        completedOrFailed = !success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completedOrFailed = YES;
                    }
                }
                if (completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Mark the input as finished, but only if we haven't already done so, and then leave the dispatch group (since the audio work has finished).
                    BOOL oldFinished = self.audioFinished;
                    self.audioFinished = YES;
                    if (oldFinished == NO)
                    {
                        [self.assetWriterAudioInput markAsFinished];
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup);
                }
            }];
        }

        if (self.assetWriterVideoInput)
        {
            // If we had video to reencode, enter the dispatch group before beginning the work.
            dispatch_group_enter(self.dispatchGroup);
            // Specify the block to execute when the asset writer is ready for video media data, and specify the queue to call it on.
            [self.assetWriterVideoInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:self.rwVideoSerializationQueue usingBlock:^{
                // Because the block is called asynchronously, check to see whether its task is complete.
                if (self.videoFinished)
                    return;
                BOOL completedOrFailed = NO;
                // If the task isn't complete yet, make sure that the input is actually ready for more media data.
                while ([self.assetWriterVideoInput isReadyForMoreMediaData] && !completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Get the next video sample buffer, and append it to the output file.
                    CMSampleBufferRef sampleBuffer = [self.assetReaderVideoOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
                    if (sampleBuffer != NULL)
                    {
                        BOOL success = [self.assetWriterVideoInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
                        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);
                        sampleBuffer = NULL;
                        completedOrFailed = !success;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        completedOrFailed = YES;
                    }
                }
                if (completedOrFailed)
                {
                    // Mark the input as finished, but only if we haven't already done so, and then leave the dispatch group (since the video work has finished).
                    BOOL oldFinished = self.videoFinished;
                    self.videoFinished = YES;
                    if (oldFinished == NO)
                    {
                        [self.assetWriterVideoInput markAsFinished];
                    }
                    dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup);
                }
            }];
        }
        // Set up the notification that the dispatch group will send when the audio and video work have both finished.
        dispatch_group_notify(self.dispatchGroup, self.mainSerializationQueue, ^{
            BOOL finalSuccess = YES;
            NSError *finalError = nil;
            // Check to see if the work has finished due to cancellation.
            if (self.cancelled)
            {
                // If so, cancel the reader and writer.
                [self.assetReader cancelReading];
                [self.assetWriter cancelWriting];
            }
            else
            {
                // If cancellation didn't occur, first make sure that the asset reader didn't fail.
                if ([self.assetReader status] == AVAssetReaderStatusFailed)
                {
                    finalSuccess = NO;
                    finalError = [self.assetReader error];
                }
                // If the asset reader didn't fail, attempt to stop the asset writer and check for any errors.
            }

            if (finalSuccess)
            {
                [self.assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{
                    NSError *finalError = nil;
                    if(self.assetWriter.status == AVAssetWriterStatusFailed)
                    {
                        finalError = self.assetWriter.error;
                    }

                    [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:finalError==nil
                                                       withError:finalError];
                }];
                return;
            }
            // Call the method to handle completion, and pass in the appropriate parameters to indicate whether reencoding was successful.
            [self readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:finalSuccess withError:finalError];
        });
    }
}

- (void)readingAndWritingDidFinishSuccessfully:(BOOL)success withError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (!success)
    {
        // If the reencoding process failed, we need to cancel the asset reader and writer.
        [self.assetReader cancelReading];
        [self.assetWriter cancelWriting];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (self.completionBlock) {
                self.completionBlock(NO);
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
        // Reencoding was successful, reset booleans.
        self.cancelled = NO;
        self.videoFinished = NO;
        self.audioFinished = NO;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (self.completionBlock) {
                self.completionBlock(YES);
            }
        });
    }
}

- (void)cancel
{
    // Handle cancellation asynchronously, but serialize it with the main queue.
    dispatch_async(self.mainSerializationQueue, ^{
        // If we had audio data to reencode, we need to cancel the audio work.
        if (self.assetWriterAudioInput)
        {
            // Handle cancellation asynchronously again, but this time serialize it with the audio queue.
            dispatch_async(self.rwAudioSerializationQueue, ^{
                // Update the Boolean property indicating the task is complete and mark the input as finished if it hasn't already been marked as such.
                BOOL oldFinished = self.audioFinished;
                self.audioFinished = YES;
                if (oldFinished == NO)
                {
                    [self.assetWriterAudioInput markAsFinished];
                }
                // Leave the dispatch group since the audio work is finished now.
                dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup);
            });
        }

        if (self.assetWriterVideoInput)
        {
            // Handle cancellation asynchronously again, but this time serialize it with the video queue.
            dispatch_async(self.rwVideoSerializationQueue, ^{
                // Update the Boolean property indicating the task is complete and mark the input as finished if it hasn't already been marked as such.
                BOOL oldFinished = self.videoFinished;
                self.videoFinished = YES;
                if (oldFinished == NO)
                {
                    [self.assetWriterVideoInput markAsFinished];
                }
                // Leave the dispatch group, since the video work is finished now.
                dispatch_group_leave(self.dispatchGroup);
            });
        }
        // Set the cancelled Boolean property to YES to cancel any work on the main queue as well.
        self.cancelled = YES;
    });
}


@end
```

Comment: What is SCDeviceModel? in this..?

Comment: oh, sorry, you can remove the area - I use it to use smaller video for older devices

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will implement this.

Comment: I got crash, "-[AVAssetWriter initWithURL:fileType:error:] invalid parameter not satisfying: [outputURL isFileURL]'"

Comment: I am Usining "    NSString* myDocumentPath= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"TEST.MOV"];
" as a output URL

Comment: You need to provide a url, not a NSString! [NSURL fileURLWithString: myDocumentPath]; or [NSURL URLWithString: myDocumentPath];

Comment: Yes I was convert this NSString to Document directory URL..is this not enough ?

Comment: Like this [NSURL URLWithString:myDocumentPath]

Comment: is it possible to set GIF image with video? see my question please..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31237876/is-it-possible-to-set-gif-image-with-video

Answer (score 0):

```
[composition  addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
```

into

```
AVMutableCompositionTrack *theTrack = [composition  addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
```

fix your time range,height,width etc.

Comment: My issue is crop video from top this all the things I have done already